# Replacement for RemoteTokenServices in Spring Security 5.2.x

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am migrating an app from Spring Security OAuth 2.x to Spring Security 5.2.x

My application (which is a resource server) talks to an auth server that requires a clientId and clientSecret to validate JWT tokens.

We used to use "org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.RemoteTokenServices" to specify the auth server's url, client Id and client secret in the old library and I wanted to know how to do this now that we are using Spring Security 5.2.x

I tried going through this but couldn't figure it out - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for  https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/html5/#specifying-a-token-verification-strategy?